# How to replicate the styling of html heading tags

Tags: css, tags, styling, html-heading

Can anyone tell me how to replicate the styling of a `<h3>` tag using CSS?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do replicate a h3 tag

Comment: generally speaking, things that aren't headings shouldn't look like headings.  It's misleading.  The point of a heading is semantic, not presentational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: "Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4" http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

```
display: block;
font-size: 1.17em;
margin: .83em 0;
font-weight: bolder;
```

Of course, Kendrick is right in saying that browsers may use different formatting than suggested by the W3C.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the H3 tag is chosen by the browser, so you may be able to replicate it for one browser but it won't necessarily map to another one...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Firefox's style for all browser's, you can look in the "computed styles" tab of firebug when inspecting an h3 element with it, and copy what you see in a CSS file.